# Performing PInvoke based on a .h file only

Tags: pinvoke

Is it possible to do P/I if I only have the .header interface file with methods exposed?

Comment: No - you should at least have the DLL, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean code and compile your PInvoke call, yes you can do it with the header only.

Of course if you want to run it you'll need the DLL too.

Comment: How difficult will this task be?

I can't seem to find any information on P/Invoke other than www.pinvoke.net.

What sort of information do I need? Do I need to download any external software, or learn P/Invoke syntax or something?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not difficult, it just takes some time to understand the logic. You'll find good tutorials on Google. There is apparently an addin for Visual Studio that can help you: http://www.red-gate.com/products/pinvoke.net

(I haven't tested it)